# POST application/x-www-form-urlencoded to Server with AFNetworking 2.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, apache, cocoa-touch, afnetworking-2

I'm trying to post data to a server which successfully connects, but does not take the data I'm passing through the parameter. The server is set to take `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I looked up some examples on here, but did not see a fix for it.

My parameter looks like this:

```
parameter = @{@ "key1" : value1,
                "key2" : value2};
```

and my method is this:

```
- (void)postDataToServer:(NSDictionary*)parameters{

    NSString *URLString = @"http://urlInfo";
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];

    [manager POST:URLString
       parameters:parameters
          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
        {
        NSLog(@"responseObject: %@", responseObject);
        NSLog(@"operation.responseString: %@",operation.responseString);
        NSLog(@"operation.response: %@",operation.response);

    }
          failure:
     ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
         NSLog(@"Error Response --> %@",operation.responseString);
     }];
}
```

My responses from the success block are as follows:

```
responseObject: <>
operation.responseString: 
operation.response: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x37cd60> { URL: http://urlInfo } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 0;
    Date = "Mon, 24 Nov 2014 03:06:22 GMT";
    Server = "Apache-Coyote/1.1";
} }
```

Can someone please point out what is missing here? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you setting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as an acceptable response content type?

Comment: Also, why are you initializing a new manager for each request? Either use the shared manager or create a new property.

Comment: I'll switch to a shared manager. Thanks for that tip. For the acceptable content type, do I not have to set that if I want to pass the server that data, or is that just for pulling from the server? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a server issue, if an issue at all. The server returns a 200 code, which usually denotes success. As posted, the code is sending the POST body as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Unless you're expecting the server to echo the response data, I'm not sure what the issue is...